# Install NVIDIA GPU Drivers on Kali Linux and notebook

Tags: debian, nvidia-graphics-card, kali-linux

I am trying to make Kali to recognize my NVIDIA graphics card and use it instead of the integrated graphic processor. I am linking the [NVIDIA drivers step-by-step manual](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux/) from the Kali webpage, which I follow, but which gives me different results than expected by the webpage.

Doing the instructions for the first time, I got no errors. However, the card was not installed properly as the internal processor was still in use. I have purged away all the packages but ended up with broken packages and could not reinstall them manually. To fix that I made all the steps again but used `aptitude` instead of `apt` in order to re-install all the missing references.

What I have by now is the following. Please open the link above in order to compare the outputs.

```
1. sudo aptitude update
```

```
2. sudo aptitude -y full-upgrade -y
```

```
3. [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && sudo reboot -f
```

```
4. lspci | grep -i vga
-> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
```

```
5. sudo aptitude install nvidia-detect
```

```
6. nvidia-detect
-> Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)

Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
Uh oh. Failed to identify your Debian suite.
```

```
7. lspci -s 01:00.0 -v
-> 01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133, IOMMU group 1
        Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidia
```

By now, we can see that the kernel driver in use is `nvidia`, which is already different from `nouveau`.

```
8. sudo aptitude install -y nvidia-driver nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

```
9. sudo reboot -f
```

```
10. nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.103.01   Driver Version: 470.103.01   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   36C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      4MiB /  4042MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       720      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

At this moment I am not sure if everything is ok, because the corresponding table in the manual shows more data and includes the `xfwm4` process which is not active on my side.

```
11. lspci | grep -i vga
-> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
```

At this point in the manual, my NVIDIA card has to be shown. Instead, the integrated processor only is listed.

```
12. lspci -s 00:02.0 -v
-> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] HD Graphics 630
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129, IOMMU group 2
        Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

```
13. lspci -s 01:00.0 -v
-> 01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133, IOMMU group 1
        Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidia
```

```
14. sudo aptitude install -y hashcat
```

```
15. hashcat -I
-> hashcat (v6.2.5) starting in backend information mode

CUDA Info:
==========

CUDA.Version.: 11.4

Backend Device ID #1 (Alias: #2)
  Name...........: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
  Processor(s)...: 5
  Clock..........: 1493
  Memory.Total...: 4042 MB
  Memory.Free....: 3996 MB
  PCI.Addr.BDFe..: 0000:01:00.0

OpenCL Info:
============

OpenCL Platform ID #1
  Vendor..: NVIDIA Corporation
  Name....: NVIDIA CUDA
  Version.: OpenCL 3.0 CUDA 11.4.189

  Backend Device ID #2 (Alias: #1)
    Type...........: GPU
    Vendor.ID......: 32
    Vendor.........: NVIDIA Corporation
    Name...........: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
    Version........: OpenCL 3.0 CUDA
    Processor(s)...: 5
    Clock..........: 1493
    Memory.Total...: 4042 MB (limited to 1010 MB allocatable in one block)
    Memory.Free....: 3968 MB
    OpenCL.Version.: OpenCL C 1.2 
    Driver.Version.: 470.103.01
    PCI.Addr.BDF...: 01:00.0
...
```

When I try to troubleshoot:

```
16. sudo aptitude install -y clinfo
```

```
17. clinfo
-> Number of platforms                               2
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 3.0 CUDA 11.4.189
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
...
...
Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 3.0 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  470.103.01
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
...
...
```

```
18. dpkg -l | grep -i icd
ii  nvidia-egl-icd:amd64                   470.103.01-3                         amd64        NVIDIA EGL installable client driver (ICD)
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd:amd64                470.103.01-3                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL installable client driver (ICD)
ii  nvidia-vulkan-icd:amd64                470.103.01-3                         amd64        NVIDIA Vulkan installable client driver (ICD)
ii  ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64               2.2.14-3                             amd64        Generic OpenCL ICD Loader
ii  ocl-icd-opencl-dev:amd64               2.2.14-3                             amd64        OpenCL development files
ii  pocl-opencl-icd:amd64                  1.8-3                                amd64        pocl ICD
```

```
19. dpkg -l | grep -i mesa-opencl-icd
-> (nothing)
```

```
20. clinfo | grep -i "icd loader"
ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.14
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 3.0
```

```
21. nvidia-smi -i 0 -q
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                                 : Thu Apr 21 17:56:28 2022
Driver Version                            : 470.103.01
CUDA Version                              : 11.4

Attached GPUs                             : 1
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
    Product Name                          : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
    Product Brand                         : GeForce
    Display Mode                          : Disabled
    Display Active                        : Disabled
    Persistence Mode                      : Disabled
    MIG Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    Accounting Mode                       : Disabled
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size           : 4000
    Driver Model
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    Serial Number                         : N/A
    GPU UUID                              : GPU-ebf9898c-5602-0704-980f-3c0d37c16812
    Minor Number                          : 0
    VBIOS Version                         : 86.07.3C.00.13
    MultiGPU Board                        : No
    Board ID                              : 0x100
    GPU Part Number                       : N/A
    Module ID                             : 0
    Inforom Version
        Image Version                     : N/A
        OEM Object                        : N/A
        ECC Object                        : N/A
        Power Management Object           : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    GSP Firmware Version                  : N/A
    GPU Virtualization Mode
        Virtualization Mode               : None
        Host VGPU Mode                    : N/A
    IBMNPU
        Relaxed Ordering Mode             : N/A
    PCI
        Bus                               : 0x01
        Device                            : 0x00
        Domain                            : 0x0000
        Device Id                         : 0x1C8D10DE
        Bus Id                            : 00000000:01:00.0
        Sub System Id                     : 0x11281025
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                       : 3
                Current                   : 1
            Link Width
                Max                       : 16x
                Current                   : 16x
        Bridge Chip
            Type                          : N/A
            Firmware                      : N/A
        Replays Since Reset               : 0
        Replay Number Rollovers           : 0
        Tx Throughput                     : 0 KB/s
        Rx Throughput                     : 0 KB/s
    Fan Speed                             : N/A
    Performance State                     : P8
    Clocks Throttle Reasons
        Idle                              : Active
        Applications Clocks Setting       : Not Active
        SW Power Cap                      : Not Active
        HW Slowdown                       : Not Active
            HW Thermal Slowdown           : Not Active
            HW Power Brake Slowdown       : Not Active
        Sync Boost                        : Not Active
        SW Thermal Slowdown               : Not Active
        Display Clock Setting             : Not Active
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                             : 4042 MiB
        Used                              : 4 MiB
        Free                              : 4038 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                             : 256 MiB
        Used                              : 2 MiB
        Free                              : 254 MiB
    Compute Mode                          : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                               : 0 %
        Memory                            : 0 %
        Encoder                           : 0 %
        Decoder                           : 0 %
    Encoder Stats
        Active Sessions                   : 0
        Average FPS                       : 0
        Average Latency                   : 0
    FBC Stats
        Active Sessions                   : 0
        Average FPS                       : 0
        Average Latency                   : 0
    Ecc Mode
        Current                           : N/A
        Pending                           : N/A
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory             : N/A
                Register File             : N/A
                L1 Cache                  : N/A
                L2 Cache                  : N/A
                Texture Memory            : N/A
                Texture Shared            : N/A
                CBU                       : N/A
                Total                     : N/A
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory             : N/A
                Register File             : N/A
                L1 Cache                  : N/A
                L2 Cache                  : N/A
                Texture Memory            : N/A
                Texture Shared            : N/A
                CBU                       : N/A
                Total                     : N/A
        Aggregate
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory             : N/A
                Register File             : N/A
                L1 Cache                  : N/A
                L2 Cache                  : N/A
                Texture Memory            : N/A
                Texture Shared            : N/A
                CBU                       : N/A
                Total                     : N/A
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory             : N/A
                Register File             : N/A
                L1 Cache                  : N/A
                L2 Cache                  : N/A
                Texture Memory            : N/A
                Texture Shared            : N/A
                CBU                       : N/A
                Total                     : N/A
    Retired Pages
        Single Bit ECC                    : N/A
        Double Bit ECC                    : N/A
        Pending Page Blacklist            : N/A
    Remapped Rows                         : N/A
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp                  : 39 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp                 : 102 C
        GPU Slowdown Temp                 : 97 C
        GPU Max Operating Temp            : 94 C
        GPU Target Temperature            : N/A
        Memory Current Temp               : N/A
        Memory Max Operating Temp         : N/A
    Power Readings
        Power Management                  : N/A
        Power Draw                        : N/A
        Power Limit                       : N/A
        Default Power Limit               : N/A
        Enforced Power Limit              : N/A
        Min Power Limit                   : N/A
        Max Power Limit                   : N/A
    Clocks
        Graphics                          : 139 MHz
        SM                                : 139 MHz
        Memory                            : 405 MHz
        Video                             : 544 MHz
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
        Memory                            : N/A
    Default Applications Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
        Memory                            : N/A
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                          : 1911 MHz
        SM                                : 1911 MHz
        Memory                            : 3504 MHz
        Video                             : 1708 MHz
    Max Customer Boost Clocks
        Graphics                          : N/A
    Clock Policy
        Auto Boost                        : N/A
        Auto Boost Default                : N/A
    Voltage
        Graphics                          : N/A
    Processes
        GPU instance ID                   : N/A
        Compute instance ID               : N/A
        Process ID                        : 720
            Type                          : G
            Name                          : /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
            Used GPU Memory               : 4 MiB
```

Here it looks like NVIDIA is not recognized correctly, being "disabled" or "N/A" in many fields.

```
22. sudo aptitude install -y mesa-utils
```

```
23. glxinfo | grep -i "direct rendering" 
-> direct rendering: Yes
```

By now I do not know what to do. Some steps seem to be successful, but I do not understand why the NVIDIA card is not listed under VGA-s and why the notebook does not want to use it.

Would you have any idea about how to fix the installation or where the problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

This is the official documentation https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux/

For optimus (laptops and notebooks), you will not see NVIDIA for the primary card. You may also not even see NVIDIA listed at all. You can see what the primary card is by doing:

```sh
kali@kali:~$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
kali@kali:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing-Nvidia-drivers-on-Kali-Linux

The tutorial found on [Kali's official website](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux) is broken as of date 11 April 2018

After spending few days on how-tos and debugging the black screen issue on boot after insalling the nvidia drivers, I was finally able to find a solution to all my problems. The main reason I'm writing this post is to let you know that the tutorial found on Kali's official website is broken as of date 11 April 2018. According to he mentioned in their website you might be able to successfully install the packages - ocl-icd-libopencl1, nvidia-driver, nvidia-cuda-toolkit but you might encounter issues during the reboot. You might get a black screen and won't be able to login via the GUI.

Try to see this repo https://github.com/europa502/Installing-Nvidia-drivers-on-Kali-Linux.git